How to model a controlled experiment (three time points, two groups) in lme4?
We conducted a behavior change field experiment using the following variables:

Three time points (T0, T1, T2)
Two groups (intervention vs. control)
Individual ID
Workshop ID

The intervention was administered in separate groups, workshops, using the lme4 package in R. We planned to compare group differences at T1 and T2 (separately because of small sample/drop-out) with T0 scores as covariates and two random intercepts. We sub-selected T1 rows and added T0 columns for all DVs.
For example:
model_1_post_self_efficacy <- lmer(self_efficacy ~ T0_self_efficacy + group + (1 | individual_ID) +(1 | workshop_ID), data = data_T1_baseline)

This doesn't work because there is only one row per individual_ID. It does work when we use a dataset consisting of T0 and T1 rows plus the T0 covariate columns. However, conceptually, it seems odd to predict a DV across T0 and T1 with T0_DV as a covariate.
Alternatively, a model without a covariate, but instead a time * group interaction + individual_ID + workshop_ID as random intercepts) works too.
model_4_post_self_efficacy <- lmer(self_efficacy ~ time * group + (1 | workshop_ID) + (1 | individual_ID), data = data_T1_T0)

My questions are:

Is there a way to sensibly combine both covariates and individual random effects
How do we best decide what to do?


Greetings and welcome to CV! I tried to rearrange the information a bit to make it easier to understand, but I still have some questions. First, aren't the individuals technically nested within the workshops? Or did each individual involve themselves in every workshop, so that they are not independent groups? Second, the original model you had doesn't really make sense to me, but I'm still a bit confused by your second model. If I am not mistaken, the second model simply tries to predict self efficacy with the main/interaction effects of time (0-2) and group (ctrl/trt) and the REs?

Why can't you arrange your data as having with 2 rows per participant (T1 and T2), a time variable (1, 2) and T0 column and predict self-efficacy from T0, time, group, and time*group, with a random intercept of (1|workshop/participant) (I agree with Shawn Hemelstrand, your participants are nested within workshops)?

Thank you so much both! Each individual in the intervention condition only attended one of 7 workshop. In the control condition, there were no workshops so I coded that as 99 for everyone. I would run two separate models for T1 and T2 because the sample size is very low at T2 (drop out in a field study). Yes, the second group would predict Self-efficacy from time (T0/T1) * group (ctrl/trt) + REs.

Thanks for raising the nested structure (1|workshop/participant) -- we adjusted it and it doesn't change the results. :)

@AnnaBosshard I have to cast doubt on the model not changing at all after using a hierarchical random effects structure over crossed random effects. An example of each fitting is shown here. However, it seems clear from your explanation that the hierarchical structure is the more accurate model here.

Can you specify how much data you had at each time period? A "small" sample here is a bit limited as a description, and it may be important to understand why there was a significant dropout in the first place.

OK, I hope I understood correctly!
First, I would perhaps forget T2 data altogether, if there was heavy drop out between T1 and T2.
So, you can use the multilevel model approach or the covariate approach, not both at the same time. If you use a multilevel model, you'd arrange your data so that each participant has 2 rows, T0 and T1, and use something like
model1<-lmer(DV ~ time*group + (1|workshop/participant), data=data)

#time here would be T0 vs T1

An alternative way to analyze the data is an ANCOVA in which you run a single-level model predicting T1 scores from group and T0 scores, like
model2<-aov(T1 ~ group + T0, data=data)

#however, I'm not sure how to incorporate the workshop into the ANCOVA approach


I'm not sure I agree with the advice that T2 data should be completely ignored. Some important factors to consider: is the dropout a lot? (A dropout of 1% is certainly not the same as 90%). Is the dropout predictable? How many observations are leftover at T2? The "small" sample here leaves a bit of ambiguity about what should be done about it as well.

Of course, it depends on the amount of dropout. I often see late-stage-dropout rates that change the whole premise of the study if the last measurement point is included.

Thank you so much for your help!

The reason to not do the model where you treat time 0 as an observation is that you make additional assumptions about the distribution. These assumptions are sometimes badly violated, e.g. when you only include those with time 0 > some threshold X (or < X) in your experiment (that's pretty common in clinical trials).
You definitely need to account for workshop id, because that's your unit of randomization. There's a whole extensive literature on cluster randomized trials, which this appears to be. I'd bet this literature covers this topic.
The below works sensibly, I think:
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)
example <- tibble(group=rep(0L:1L, each=100),
                  workshop_id = rep(1L:20L, each=10),
                  workshop_re = rep(rnorm(n=20, mean=0, sd=25), each=10),
                  subject = 1L:200L,
                  T0 = rnorm(n=200, mean=0, sd=3),
                  T1 = T0  + workshop_re + group*5 +rnorm(n=200, mean=0 , sd=0.5),
                  T2 = T1 + rnorm(n=200, mean=0, sd=1)) %>%
  mutate(group=factor(group),
         workshop_id = factor(workshop_id),
         subject=factor(subject)) %>%
  dplyr::select(-workshop_re)

example %>% 
  mutate(CHG1=T1-T0,
         CHG2=T2-T0) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols=c("T0", "T1", "T2", "CHG1", "CHG2"), names_to="Time", values_to="Value") %>%
  mutate(Time=factor(Time, levels=c("T0", "T1", "T2", "CHG1", "CHG2"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=workshop_id, col=group, y=Value)) +
  theme_bw(base_size=18) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette="Dark2") +
  geom_point(alpha=0.3) +
  facet_wrap(~Time, labeller=label_both, scales="free")


example %>%
  group_by(group, workshop_id) %>%
  summarize(n=n(), .groups="drop")

A simple model for time 1 would be this:
lme4::lmer( T1 ~ 1 + group + T0 + (1|workshop_id), 
            data=example)

which generates this:
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: T1 ~ 1 + group + T0 + (1 | workshop_id)
   Data: example
REML criterion at convergence: 485.5589
Random effects:
 Groups      Name        Std.Dev.
 workshop_id (Intercept) 24.9226 
 Residual                 0.5013 
Number of obs: 200, groups:  workshop_id, 20
Fixed Effects:
(Intercept)       group1           T0  
     1.9156       8.2635       0.9841 

A simple model for time 2 would be this:
lme4::lmer( T2 ~ 1 + group + T0 + (1|workshop_id), 
            data=example)

which generates this:
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: T2 ~ 1 + group + T0 + (1 | workshop_id)
   Data: example
REML criterion at convergence: 770.1621
Random effects:
 Groups      Name        Std.Dev.
 workshop_id (Intercept) 24.95   
 Residual                 1.11   
Number of obs: 200, groups:  workshop_id, 20
Fixed Effects:
(Intercept)       group1           T0  
      2.009        8.129        0.985  

Here is a model over the two timepoints:
lme4::lmer( Value ~ 1 + Time + T0 + Time:T0 + group + group:Time + (1|workshop_id/subject) , 
            data=example %>%
              pivot_longer(cols=c("T1", "T2"), names_to="Time", values_to="Value") %>%
              mutate(Time=factor(Time, levels=c("T1", "T2"))))

Generates this:
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: Value ~ 1 + Time + T0 + Time:T0 + group + group:Time + (1 | workshop_id/subject)
   Data: example %>% pivot_longer(cols = c("T1", "T2"), names_to = "Time",  
    values_to = "Value") %>% mutate(Time = factor(Time, levels = c("T1",      "T2")))
REML criterion at convergence: 1177.97
Random effects:
 Groups              Name        Std.Dev.
 subject:workshop_id (Intercept)  0.4943 
 workshop_id         (Intercept) 24.9362 
 Residual                         0.7017 
Number of obs: 400, groups:  subject:workshop_id, 200; workshop_id, 20
Fixed Effects:
  (Intercept)         TimeT2             T0         group1      TimeT2:T0  TimeT2:group1  
     1.915535       0.093232       0.983370       8.263421       0.002348      -0.134439

One one might criticize here is that you don't allow for a different residual error at the two timepoints, when often variability increases with time. A package that lets you account for that (as well as different correlation structures by group, or flexible correlation over more than 2 timepoints is the mmrm package).
When there's no missing data/no drop-outs, then plus-minus some minor things with exactly how you specify your model you should get extremely similar results whether you fit a separate model per time-point or an appropriate mixed model (or MMRM) across the timepoints. When there's missing data/drop-outs, you get an implicit imputation (that lets you target hypothetical estimand that everything about those with missing data would have continued as per the trends seen in those that continued, assuming missing at random), if you don't like that / the assumption do an explicit imputation in the way you want and analyze the timepoints separately.

Thank you very much Björn, this is helpful!
